# odoo pb integrety error

Tags: python, database, odoo, integrity

I don't understand exactly why but I have this error. the customers_group_id is present in my table

There all my relations.

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you.

```
IntegrityError: insert or update on table "products_group" violates foreign key constraint "products_group_customers_group_i_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (customers_group_id)=(25) is not present in table "customers_group".
```

My code

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp.tools.translate import _

class customers_group(osv.osv):
    _name = 'customers.group'
    _rec_name = 'customers_group_name'

    _columns = {
        'customers_group_id': fields.integer('Group Id', size=5, help="Id customer group"),
        'customers_group_name': fields.char('Group Name', size=30, required=True),
       .....
    }


class res_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _columns = {
        'partner_customer_group_id': fields.many2one('customers.group','Customers Group', help='Customers group.')
    }
```

products group

```
from openerp.osv import orm, fields
from openerp.tools.translate import _

class products_group(orm.Model):
    _name = 'products.group'

    _columns = { 
        'customers_group_id': fields.integer('Customer group Id', size=20, help='id of customers group'),
        'products_id': fields.integer('Product Id', size=5, help="Id product must be unique"),
        'products_model_group': fields.char('Product model group', size=30, help='Product model'),
        .....       
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code for "products_group"?. It is possible that you have deleted the record with id as "25" from the table "customer.group", which is why it is throwing an error of foreign key constraint violation. That means data is deleted from master table (customer.group) and its still referenced somewhere in other table. Check it.

Comment: I inserted produts_group above, No every time it's a new datas,no conflict about that.

Comment: Sorry, you have right, i create a new base and it's ok for that. Thank you for your help

Comment: didn't got you clearly, so is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes my problem is resolved,  tk

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar situation like this (adjusting to your code):

```
@api.model
def _set_null(self):
    if self.customers_group_id == 25:
        self.customers_group_id = None


_columns = {
    'customers_group_id': fields.integer('Group Id', size=5, help="Id customer group", compute='_set_null'),
   .....
}
```

I restarted the service and after I removed the method _set_null and compute attribute because the values with 25 were replaced with Null, so the integrity error should not occur anymore.